# Getting event id from Facebook event posting

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that I'm trying to write where users can view the photos that have been uploaded to an event's wall. I've managed to write a PHP script that gives me the photos and their URL's but I can't see how to get the event id that a photo has been posted against (so that each picture can be associated with the date of the event and therefore only show the appropriate ones when a user clicks on a calendar).

```
$event_id_name = 'actor_id'; //changed each attempt to something from the Facebook 'stream' table

$fql = array(
    "permsQuery"=>"SELECT user_events, create_event FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()",
    "query1"=>"SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()",
    "query2"=>"SELECT name,start_time, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #query1)",
    "query3"=> 'SELECT attachment, '.$event_id_name.' FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT eid FROM #query1)',
    "userQuery"=>"SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid = me()",
);

$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.multiquery',
 'access_token' => $access_token,
 'scope' => $required_permissions,
 'queries' => $fql,
));

//get the index of the query in the returned sets
//Yes, I'm sure there's an easier way of doing this! :)
$x = 0;
while ($x < count($ret_obj))
{
 if ($ret_obj[$x]['name'] == 'query3') {$returnedPostIndex = $x;}
 $x++;
}

//for debugging, just throw out the array elements in an relatively easy format
$x = 0;
while ($x < count($ret_obj[$returnedPostIndex][$results_set]))
{
 print_r ($ret_obj[$returnedPostIndex][$results_set][$x][$event_id_name]);
 print_r (' : ');
 print_r (count($ret_obj[$returnedPostIndex][$results_set][$x]['attachment']['media']));
 print_r (', ');
 $x++;
}
```

So using the above code, I get a line of text on my web page which has the column content and then the count of photos that were uploaded for each post on all the events for a user. The problem is that I'm hoping that

```
$ret_obj[$returnedPostIndex][$results_set][$x][$event_id_name]
```

will return the event id but I don't seem to get that at all. The result (when looking at the `actor_id` column) is:

```
694382034 : 8, 694382034 : 2, 694382034 : 1, 694382034 : 1,
```

Which shows, correctly, that there are a total of 12 photos posted over 4 posts, but I know that they're spread over 2 events so clearly actor_id isn't the event's id.

Reading [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) I expected the 'actor_id' to be

> The ID of the user, page, group, or event that published the post

I'm assuming that I'm approaching this from completely the wrong direction but am stuck now, so can someone please tell me how to access an individual photograph's associated event id?

Answer (score 0):

So I did eventually approach from a different angle: I just take the eid's of the events and store them then lazy fetch the pictures assigned to those eid's when required.